# Adding and Retrieving Data Into/From Blockchain via Web Interfaces

Tags: blockchain, web3js, truffle, metamask, ganache

I am starting to learn developing web interfaces that can add and retrieve data via blockchain. The data is not in the form of cryptocurrency but rather in something like name and ID number.

I have also learnt about metamask, ganache, web3, truffle, javascript, html, css, node.js, solidity, smart contract and json...but I am not sure how to link all of them for adding and retrieving data via blockchain. I have done some googles and youtube, but unfortunately, I could only understand a few of them. Can you help me in explaining the interactions between blockchain and web interfaces to adding and retrieving data, and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web3 is used for all the purposes you've described above. Once you've retrieved the data, you can store it in a variable and use it in your frontend applications as well. 
Here's a reference diagram : [Link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Henry_Kim2/publication/307122548/figure/fig3/AS:399757378899970@1472320994254/A-system-diagram-depicting-mediated-user-interaction-with-the-Blockchain.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are too lazy to read documentation, [here](https://www.dappuniversity.com/) are a series of good examples. They were very helpful tutorials for me.